# An error when run wordcount program in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I run wordcount program using Hadoop cdh4 ,I got an error ,couldn't understand the problem
it says "file already exist" , I deleted the output directory ,and replace it ,but still the same error appears!

Please help!

```
14/12/11 02:25:25 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/12/11 02:25:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:8020/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/training/.staging/job_201412110028_0010
14/12/11 02:25:26 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:training (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:8020/user/training/wordcountout already exists
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:8020/user/training/wordcountout already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1368)
    at wordcount1.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at wordcount1.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Thanks

Comment: Delete the output directory and *don't* replace it, let hadoop do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Azureforg!- it works finally!. I still haven't understood the logic behind that. Why it says the file exists? and Why it's not removed from Hadoop once I remove it?

Comment: Hadoop just doesn't handle path collision very well.  If there is a folder in HDFS where Hadoop wants to put its data, it won't overwrite it or add new files to it, it'll just blow up (like what happened to you).  I guess that's just a design decision on the part of the Hadoop team.